# How am I misusing generics with commons beanutils?

Tags: java, generics, apache-commons-beanutils

I have two simple interfaces:

```
public interface HasId<ID extends Serializable> extends Serializable {
  T getId();
}
```

And

```
public interface HasLongId extends HasId<Long> {
  void setId(Long id);
}
```

Now, if I have a class:

```
public class Person implements HasLongId {
  private Long id;
  private String name;

  public Long getId() {
      return this.id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
      this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
      return this.name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
  }
}
```

And I instantiate a `person`, then pass it to `BeanUtils` I get strange behavior. For example sometimes setting id using BeanUtils works fine and other times, I get an exception because it can't find the "write" method for Id.  It seems that during reflection it finds a getter for a Serializable, but not a Long and it does not find a setter for the Serializable.  It does not do this consistently, so I suspect that calling person.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("id") will not always return the same Method, but I could be wrong about that.

Anyway, this inconsistent behavior is really maddening because, for example, it will work in Eclipse, but not in Maven, or it will work for a long time and then with some unrelated change somewhere else it will stop working.

Clearly I don't understand generics well enough to understand what is happening, but can anyone explain it to me and also explain how to work around it?

Comment: Can you share the BeanUtil code you're using? Also, when it fails, what's the specific exception you get?

Comment: It is not possible that `person.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("id")` will not always return the same Method, for the same `person` object or even for different objects of the same class. Try to identify the smallest example that causes the error and look hard. You might find your mistake. If not, post the code and exception here.

Comment: It's not that it's a different method for the same person object, its a different method for the same code path under different (somehow) circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of Apache Commons BeanUtils I have used was not Java 5 aware, so it didn't know about Generics, bridge methods, and so on. I believe that's the problem, which version of BeanUtils are you using? and is it Java 5+ aware?

Comment: I'm using 1.8.3 - I believe that's the most current.

Comment: Well according to it's documentation it is JDK 1.3 compatible, that's your problem.

Comment: Spring's BeanWrapper provides similar functionality, and if you use Spring 3.0+ it is JDK 5+ compatible.

Comment: Doh! This is a known issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEANUTILS-340.  Thanks.

Comment: BeanWrapper looks like it's intended mostly for use by Spring itself.  Is it common practice to use it as a kind of object-reflection utility outside a Spring context? (I am using Spring, but these aren't Spring beans I'm dealing with.)

Comment: I have used BeanWrapper (and its implementation: BeanWrapperImpl_ in an Spring application (but outside of Spring beans) and everything is prefect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't care much for this design - I don't like interfaces merely for getters and setters.

I also wouldn't have that interface extend Serializable; single responsibility is the best advice here.

But I would try it like this:

```
public interface Identifiable<T extends Serializable> {
    T getId();
    void setId(T newId);
}

public class Person implements Identifiable<Long> {
    private Long id;
    public Long getId() { return this.id; }
    public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }        
}
```

Comment: That (with the exception of the name) was one of the iterations that I tried.  I did have HasLongId with no generics and everything worked fine, but of course, I ran into a situation where I had an id that wasn't a Long, so I switched to the interface you describe and the trouble began.  Also, if you wanted to mark a class as having an Id, how would you do it? I'm happy to update my design if that fixes my problem and also makes sense.

Comment: Since you barely have any context for the application, how do you know if there's any value in marking a class as having an ID? Someone could also have an interface called `Ambulatory` that has methods like `walk()` and `jog()` and I happen to know in the context of my application that would be useless, but I would not say that there's no value for them because I wouldn't know.  Is there something special about ID's?

Comment: You're right; I don't have any context.  I'm offering my opinion, nothing more.  But I am familiar with the context in which I've had to add IDs to components, usually in the context of primary keys and relational databases.  I don't use an interface or any scheme like yours to do it.  I just get on with it and add the IDs.